# How to hide the cursor in a terminal during a script and restore it back to normal if the command is interrupted?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So let's say I have this script that displays a little animation:

```sh
while [ condition ]
do
    echo -ne "\rfinished ᕙ( ᐕ )ᕓ "
    sleep 0.3
    echo -ne "\rfinished ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ "
    sleep 0.3
done
```

The problem is that the cursor is blinking next to the little guy dancing and this is a (minor) inconvenience to me, i would prefer if the cursor was hidden.

So I tried `tput civis` which does hide the cursor. The problem is that you need to run `tput cnorm` to take it back to normal. In my example, if I try:

```sh
tput civis
while [ condition ]
do
    echo -ne "\rfinished ᕙ( ᐕ )ᕓ "
    sleep 0.3
    echo -ne "\rfinished ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ "
    sleep 0.3
done
tput cnorm
```

This works well, unless the user `Ctrl-C`s out of my program, which will cause them to have an invisible cursor, which is really annoying.

I tried to run the script like this:

```sh
./script || tput cnorm
```

but it didn't help. (also I'd prefer to be able to run the script just with `./script`)

This started as a silly problem but now I'm genuinely curious to know how to solve it.

So, is there a solution to this problem or will I have to tolerate this little blinking cursor next to my animation?

Comment: I know that's pretty unrelated to the core of the question but, in your example, your animation is comprised of two frames inwhich the first puts the protagonist in an anatomically hazardous position regarding the fact that it would need them to dislocate their left shoulder (right for our perspective). This has bothered me much more than it should and I won't allow myself to suggest anything (specially so unprompted) but I just want to point to whom might be interested that this first frame can be replaced with `ᕙ( ᐕ )ᕹ` that feels very _"boogie"_ yet does not feel (to me) like joint abuse <3

Comment: @Ar3s thank you so much for the suggestion ! While indeed unrelated, it is much appreciated !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you use [`trap`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap)?

```
function cleanup() {
    tput cnorm
}

trap cleanup EXIT

tput civis
while [ condition ]
...
```